# How to print the data found between <rt></rt> tags, immediately following each appearance of a pattern in BASH?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have some data like this:

```
Once upon a time there AAA was a <rt>cat</rt> who lived AAA in the <rt>forest</rt>.

One day, AAA the cat AAA and his friend, a dog, <rt>went</rt> to the <rt>woods</rt> to <rt>play</rt>.

A big <rt>storm</rt> came, pulling the AAA dog into the <rt>sky</rt>.
```

For simplicity, assume I am using a while loop and only examining one line at a time, as `$string`.

I need to search for each appearance of "AAA" and print the text appearing between the next appearance of `<rt>` and `</rt>` tags, within the same line.

Here is the sample output for the first line:

```
cat
forest
```

Here is the sample output for the second line:

```
went
went
```

- Here, "went" is printed twice because `<rt>went</rt>` is the next match found after both of the "AAA"'s on the line.

Here is the sample output for the third line:

```
sky
```

I tried this with `grep`:

```
grep -Po "(?<=AAA.*<rt>)[^</rt>]*(?=</rt>)"
```

I think this should work, but it instead reports, "lookbehind assertion is not fixed length" because I used .* to match anything found between `AAA` and `<rt>`.

How can I search for each "AAA", then find the next appearance of `<rt>` and `</rt>`, and return the value find between those tags, outputting one item per "AAA" found on the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although other solutions may be faster, you could use Bash's regex matching.

```
while read -r; do
    if [[ $REPLY ]]; then
        n=0         
        for word in $REPLY; do
            [[ $word == AAA ]] && ((n++))
            if [[ $n -gt 0 && $word =~ "<rt>"(.*)"</rt>" ]]; then
                for i in $(seq $n); do
                    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
                done                
                n=0                 
            fi              
        done        
    fi      
done < file
```

```
cat
forest
went
went
sky
```

In Bash, `REPLY` is the default variable for each line when looping through a file when the line variable is not user defined.  `BASH_REMATCH` at index 1 is the occurrence of the regex matched inside the first set of parentheses `(.*)`.

To print the matches together for each line, it can be done like this:

```
while read -r; do
    if [[ $REPLY ]]; then
        n=0 
        string=()
        for word in $REPLY; do
            [[ $word == AAA ]] && ((n++))
            if [[ $n -gt 0 && $word =~ "<rt>"(.*)"</rt>" ]]; then
                for i in $(seq $n); do
                    string+=("${BASH_REMATCH[1]}")
                done
                n=0 
            fi  
        done
        [[ $string ]] && echo "${string[@]}"
    fi  
done < file
```

```
cat forest
went went
sky
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it with `awk`

```
awk  -F"</*rt>" '{for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) {n=gsub(/AAA/,"&",$i);for (j=1;j<=n;j++) print $(i+1)}}'
cat
forest
went
went
sky
```

---

How does it works.

```
awk  -F"</*rt>" '               # Set the field separator to <rt> or </rt>
    {                           # Do
    for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) {       # Run a loop for and use field 1,3,5,7 etc
        n=gsub(/AAA/,"&",$i)    # Test how many AAA there are in every field
        for (j=1;j<=n;j++)      # Run a loop for number og AAA
            print $(i+1)        # Prints the field after after the AAA n times
        }
    }
' file                          # Read the file
```

---

Printed by line

```
awk  -F"</*rt>" '{for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) {n=gsub(/AAA/,"&",$i);for (j=1;j<=n;j++) printf "%s ",$(i+1)}print ""}' file
cat forest
went went
sky
```

Answer (score 1):

I am no bash expert. someone probably could do this in one line. but I tested it against your 3 examples, and it works. It basically pulls the complete string after the first AAA. then pulls the first string between rt tag. and repeat

```
s="Once upon a time there AAA was a <rt>cat</rt> who lived AAA in the <rt>forest</rt>."
s="One day, AAA the cat AAA and his friend, a dog, <rt>went</rt> to the <rt>woods</rt> to <rt>play</rt>."
s="A big <rt>storm</rt> came, pulling the AAA dog into the <rt>sky</rt>."

while [[ $s ]]; do
    s=$(echo $s | grep -Po "(?<=AAA).*")
    s2=$(echo $s | grep -Po "(?<=<rt>)[^<]+" | head -n1)
    if [[ $s2 ]]; then
        echo $s2
    fi
done
```